# GWT Highcharts tooltip positioning

Tags: gwt, highcharts

Using GWT-Highcharts, I'm trying to set a positioner for the tooltip:

```
ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.setOption("positioner", "function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) { return { x: 160, y: 160 };");
```

This doesn't really work, I'm getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (labelWidth, labelHeight, point) { return { x: -160, y: -160 }; has no method 'call'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't add the function as a string and you also need a closing brace for the function.

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand the usecase. As far as I understand you are using the Configurable setOption and would like to supply a function call. But why if you just return static x/y-values (like 160/160)?

You could do

```
tooltip.setOption("/positioner/x", "160");
tooltip.setOption("/positioner/y", "160");
```

to achieve the same...

Comment: thanks, but i want the location to be dynamically calculated for each point, rather than a static location